# Uable to connect Ubuntu server by remoting

Tags: networking, server, ssh, firewall, ufw

Hello I'm newbie of Ubuntu system. I have some problem that I've figured out for a while but I could not solve it yet. I could not remote to Ubuntu 22.04 server from my laptop **(Putty said connection timeout)**, but, vice versa, the Ubuntu server can connect other servers. So, I checked many things that already installed such as openssh and check their status by `service ssh status` which work well. And also allow ssh from firewall by `sudo ufw allow ssh`. I still could not connect to Ubuntu server. Here are some ways that I've tried and they don't work.

1. `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`, client
2. `service ssh restart`, stop, start
3. `sudo ufw allow ssh`,
4. `sudo ufw disable`

for `ssh status` information is here

```
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: e>
 Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-05-26 12:11:57 +07; 21min ago
   Docs: man:sshd(8)
         man:sshd_config(5)
Process: 17428 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES>


Main PID: 17429 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 76801)
     Memory: 1.7M
        CPU: 30ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─17429 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"

พ.ค. 26 12:11:57 inibpm01 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
พ.ค. 26 12:11:57 inibpm01 sshd[17429]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
พ.ค. 26 12:11:57 inibpm01 sshd[17429]: Server listening on :: port 22.
พ.ค. 26 12:11:57 inibpm01 systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

for `ufw app list` information is here

```
    Available applications:
  CUPS
  OpenSSH
```

for `ufw status` information is here

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

**Can anyone suggest what should I have to solve this issue?**

*Appreciated*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Where is your server? Is it hosted by a provider like Amazon or Azure? If so, you'll need to also check the port access policies of the network firewall (accessed by the web console, not the server instances).

Comment: Just a stand alone Ubuntu Desktop with a normal wired connection in my house.

Comment: Do you know your server/desktop IP address and can you ping it?

Comment: Yes I know it from ifconfig. From Ubuntu I can ping out to google and another server. But, vice versa, the another side can not ping to Ubuntu, it said port 22: connection refused.